# Как лучше реализовать корзину на spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

Делаю интернет магазин и столкнулся с проблемой создания корзины. Есть два варианта:

1. Сделать корзину отдельной таблицей в БД со связью с таблицами товаров и покупателей.
2. Попробовать сделать чрез cookie, но с ними я не сталкивался и как сделать пока не знаю.

Собственно вопрос, как реализовать лучше, какие есть ещё варианты и чем они лучше/хуже?

Comment: Лучше хранить покупки в базе.

Comment: Пользователь может удалить cookies и тогда будет горе.

Comment: @notaProgrammer а ещё кука может устареть или пользователь может пересесть за другой компьютер. С вариантом на куках невозможно отслеживать брошенные корзины и труднее вести статистику по сделанным заказам.

Comment: Когда связь с базой данных пропадает то нужно искать другое хранилище.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше хранить корзину в базе данных. Потому что по ней потом можно собирать отчеты, она не будет ходить в каждом запросе пользователя в заголовках и ее можно запросить самому в базе если это понадобится.